# What is the complexity of breadth first search for a complete graph?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

The complexity of BFS is said to be linear ie., O(V+E) but the total number of edges in a directed complete graph are V*(V-1) which is a degree 2 function of the size of the graph. So would the BFS take O(V^2) time to traverse through a complete graph?

Comment: Check the answer. Sorry for the inconvenices. I didnt see that algirthm was BFS. check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I assume you already did the math.

```
O(V+E) = O(V + V*(V-1))
       = O(V + V*V - V)
       = O(V*V)
```

Comment: Given this result, can we conclude that the worst case of BFS using adjacency list is not linear but instead quadratic?

Comment: @UttakarshTikku It's linear in the size of the input for the algorithm, which is quadratic in the number of vertices.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was great help!

Answer (score 1):

BFS runs in `O(V + E)` time provided the graph is represented by the adjacency list structure.

In the dense case also, you will see the answer will be `O(V+E)`. (Representation is adjacency list).

In case of Adjacency matrix `O(V^2)`.

No matter how the graph is , you will always first cover the neighbor of the starting point. Then repeat this for the neighbors too. So you can see that it will always have to  traverse in `O(V+E)` time but it is the representation that makes it hard for adjacency matrix. So it will be `O(V^2)`<sub>1</sub>.

<sub>1</sub><sub>This is because every time we want to find what are the edges adjacent to a given vertex 'u', we traverse the whole array `adjmatrix[u]`, which is of length |V|</sub>

Comment: What I am getting at here is the relationship between the number of vertices and the number of edges here. The number of edges in a complete graph is a function of the number of vertices, precisely V*(V-1) for a complete directed graph.

Comment: yes but representation matters. that's what i said.